# Django overlay UpdateView over a ListView

Tags: django, django-views

It is a bit of an open question, but I don't know where to start looking for an answer. I would like to have a simple ListView page, where there are items of a Model. If you click on an item, an overlay div comes (this is done with CSS/JavaScript). I would like to have the UpdateView's form (belonging to the clicked item) on this overlay div. So I am still at the same URL and I would prefer not to change it. Is this possible? If yes how? I am not asking you to write me code, just could you direct me somewhere to look for a solution? Thank you.

Comment: You could have a different form for each record in a modal and when the record is clicked it opens the relevant modal to edit or the better way is a single modal and ajax call back to your database to fill in the modal and populate it.

Comment: I go an read on it, please let me come back to you if I already have a more exact question.